# Is there a way to create a Facebook event from a native android app?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, native

I am using Facebook SDK in my native android Java app. I want to enable users to create events from inside the app on my app's Facebook page so I will later notify my other app users about the event.

Calling the graph Api edge `/appid/official_events/`, using an app token, I get

```
(#3) Application does not have the capability to make this API call
```

Documentation says that an app token cannot be used from a native app, for security reasons.
Is this the case? Should I have a server to implement this feature? Or should I request Facebook to become an 'official events' partner?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/official-events/

(this is my first post ever, excuse me for being verbose)

Comment: Yes app access token requests needs to be done from your server.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying this, I just wanted to be sure..